# Noun that describes something which checks for uniqueness between separate entities

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to determine a better word to describe a role for an entity that checks for uniqueness between two objects.

For example: if I wanted to check for duplicate records in an excel spreadsheet, is there a single non-compound word to describe the tool which executes that action.

Right now we are going with "DuplicateChecker", but it feels a bit ... unrefined.

Comment: The uppercase 'C' in "DuplicateChecker" sure looks unrefined to me. I'd accept almost anything except that ... lowercase, space, hyphen, ,,,

Comment: @RossMurray Well it's being utilized in context of software. Where Pascal casing is appropriate. I'm more so trying to see if a single word exists that matches the criteria.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for things is specifically off-topic according to our help center.

Comment: @tchrist I don't see how it's off topic; I'm curious if there is a noun that exists that describes the criteria stated. For example: a designer is one who designs . Is there a similar noun for one who compares objects for their uniqueness? I suppose comparer , but is vague . :/.      I'm guessing there isn't a word for this :)

Comment: @Ealianis [Because our Help Center says that questions regarding “Naming, including naming programming variables/classes” are off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You didn’t like `DuplicateChecker` so asked for a better name. This is a programming question.

Comment: @tchrist I humbly disagree, I understand what you are saying. But how intend on using it has nothing to do with my question. 

I'm simply try to find out if there is an English noun that encompasses that rule. But it's fine I understand why you would see it that way.

Thank you all for the submissions.

Comment: @Ealianis Humility is a virtue, so I'll reopen it for you. Can't speak for the broader community, though, who may see things differently here.

Comment: @tchrist You are an admin for a reason, I trust your judgment, I just wanted to voice my perspective on the issue at hand (the validity of my post).

Thank you for being kind, I will close it in two days if no answer is found. It doesn't appear that there is a word that fits within the constraints I've set. 

For context: there is a standard in which we are to utilize nouns, e.g. Auditor, Manager, Logger, Enforcer, etc.. That is my argument for it not being a programming question.

Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

How about "comparator"? It's used a lot more often in electronics than every day life, but I've heard it make it's way into other discussions now and that's what it means.

com·par·a·tor
kəmˈperədər/
noun
noun: comparator; plural noun: comparators

```
a device for comparing a measurable property or thing with a reference or standard.
    an electronic circuit for comparing two electrical signals.
    something used as a standard for comparison.
```

Comment: Another similar term is "differentiator".

Comment: You need to cite what source that definition comes from.

Answer (score -2):

I admit this is jargony, but I have encountered **dedupe** in two unrelated settings as a verb for the process of removing duplicates.

It turns out it has at least two [online](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dedupe) dictionary [definitions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dedupe)

So "deduper" would not be wrong, even though it looks ... unrefined.

Comment: A deduplicator/deduper *removes* duplicates, but OP is asking for something that *finds* duplicates.